# Recursion - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion

I am required to write a recursive method.  I have written the code to perform the task without recursion.  I am getting the error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at Exercise13r.recursion(Exercise13r.java:29)**.  Code is... to enter a number then if result is even, divide by 2, if result is odd, multiply by 3 and subtract 1.  Obviously I am looping but not sure why.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise13r
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Initialize variables
        long number = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter a starting number: ");
        number = in.nextInt ();
        System.out.println ("Your starting number is: " + number);
        if (number != 1)
        {
            recursion(number);
        }
    }

    public static void recursion(long n)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            recursion(n/2);
        }
        else
        {
            recursion(n*3-1);
        }
    System.out.println ("number: " + n);
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Program to stop when number result = 1

Comment: You need to move the "should I stop now" check inside `recursion`. As it stands, both branches of the `if` call the function again, and it loops forever.

Comment: in which situation do you think you can exit the `recursion` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base case `if (number != 1)` needs to be inside the definition of the function so that it actually knows when to stop. Right now your program eventually reduces to calling `recursion(1)` and your function will still call itself recursively (what else can it do?) so it ends up calling `recursion(2)` which leads to `recursion(1)` again and so on.

Note that this becomes apparent if you move `System.out.println ("number: " + n);` *before* the recursive calls. Since you have infinite recursion it never gets around to printing anything preventing you from seeing the problem.

[Here](https://ideone.com/CKdcVK) is a minimal working example:

```
class Exercise13r {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursion(12);
    }

    public static void recursion(long n) {
        System.out.println ("number: " + n);
        if (n != 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                recursion(n/2);
            } else {
                recursion(n*3-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
number: 12
number: 6
number: 3
number: 8
number: 4
number: 2
number: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Unfortunately that was the way I had it originally and moved it out in hopes to resolve.  Forgot to move it back before posting.  When I place it inside it still loops.                                                public static void recursion(long n)
 {
  if (n != 1)
  {
   if (n % 2 == 0)
   {
    recursion(n/2);
   }
   else
   {
    recursion(n*3-1);
   }
  System.out.println ("number: " + n);
  }
  return;
 }

Comment: Make sure that you check the base case first, and if it's true, that the function returns before it can get to the recursive calls. Also move the print so you can see what's happening. If you still can't get it then edit your question with the latest code.

Comment: Changed base case to check for true but it still loops.  Also added the print statements in each "if" statement but never get one to print.  changed code:    public static void recursion(long n)
        {
            if (n == 1) return;
            {
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                {
                     recursion(n/2);
                     System.out.println ("even number: " + n);
                }
                else
                {
                    recursion(n*3-1);
                    System.out.println ("odd number: " + n);
                }
        }

Comment: @shoes You need to print *before* the recursion to see what's happening. I can't see anything wrong with your code. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @shoes I tested both bits of code that you commented here and they worked fine. You're doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Alex - thanks for the help.  I tried your changes to the method.  it worked through a few iterations before looping and erroring again.  I did notice it only loops and errors if the input number is odd or if it is > 16.

Comment: public static void recursion(long n) {
  System.out.println ("method number: " + n);
  if (n != 1) {
   if (n % 2 == 0) {
    recursion(n/2); }
   else{recursion(n*3-1);}
  }
 }

Comment: @shoes some inputs never reach 1, they go in a cycle, e.g. 5 -> 14 -> 7 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 14 ... You can see this from the prints. There's nothing wrong with the code, it's just how the maths works out. If you use `3 * n + 1` it'll always go to 1, that's the Collatz sequence. Your particular sequence has cycles.

Comment: you helped me solve it.  I read the instruction wrong and was subtracting (3*n-1)  should have been (3*n+1).  It works!!!!   thanks so much